# Passing JDBC connection object to a method as parameter

Tags: java, jdbc

Consider the below code:

```
try (Connection conn = icrud.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM TABLE_NAME");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();)
{
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        perform_something_method(conn, rs.getLong("ID"));
    }
    perform_something_method2(conn)
    conn.commit();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    conn.rollback();
}

private void perform_something_method(Connection conn, long id) throws Exception
{
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TABLE1 SET LOGDATETIME=? WHERE ID=?");)
    {
        //perform some task
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}    

private void perform_something_method2(Connection conn) throws Exception
{
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TABLE1 SET LOGDATETIME=? WHERE ID=?");)
    {
        //perform some task
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I created `Connection` object and and executed an query using `PreparedStatement`. In `While` loop I am calling another method perform_something_method() to do some process on fetched result set. I am passing `Connection` object to that method, Is this safe?

In `perform_something_method()` method I am not closing/committing/rollback on passed `Connection` object, rather I am throwing if any exception comes in that method so that it will come back and do rollback.

So is this code correct/safe, as I am passing JDBC connection object as method parameter. Let me know if any potential risk that can happen.

Comment: better to make `conn` a non-static class member

Comment: You will need to disable auto-commit **before** executing the query, otherwise the result set might be closed by calling `setAutoCommit(false)`, or by executing the other queries (depending on the holdability property of the result set). Other than that, it is unclear to me what you're really asking. You're closing the connection with a try-with-resources, so ultimately it will be closed before that block is exited. Why do you think this might be 'unsafe'?